# Как сделать разграничения у сложных заголовков в DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Всем привет! Вопрос в следующем: у меня есть сложное приложение, как показано на рисунке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы между месяцами было разграничение. Примерно так, как показано на следующем рисунке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Я бы попробовал по ячейке на месяц и внутри каждой отрисовывал бы часть блока таймлайна.